# How to insert a radio group inside data-grid?

Tags: html, datagrid, datagridview, radio-button, radio-group

I have a rough model of my application which looks some like as shown in picture below:

[image]

I am using jquery easyui data-grid framework to get this but i am not able to insert radio group type as one of my column as shown in Status column of my picture. Can anyone please help me how to insert radio button inside data-grid table? And other thing is, is the datagrid is only way to get these type of functions or any other way through which we can get same thing? If anyone know any other way please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: ı will ask a question you. Why did you tagged this question with android and phonegap? Are you using easyui with android and phonegap? How are you doing this? Will grid or other easyui components look well on a android phone?

Comment: @Mehmet Hi thanks for the response and well i have the same doubt like can we implement this data grid type things in android tablet? Can you please tell me is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using easyui grid and other components too. You can use easyui datagrid's formatter property look [here](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php)

On formatter property you can add any innerHTML like radiobuttons,buttons,labels etc to datagridcolumns.Look my example below, I am using this sample on my project;

```
 var btnid="";
 FILL_TESTGRID: function (_data) {
            try {
                $('#TestGrid').datagrid({
                    singleSelect: true,
                    remoteSort: false,
                    fitcolumns: true,
                    nowrap: false,
                    columns: [[
                        { field: 'ID', title: 'ID', sortable: true },
                        { field: 'NAME', title: 'NAME', sortable: true },
                        { field: 'action', title: 'ColumntTitle3', formatter: function (value, row, index) {
                            var col;
                            if (row.ID!= null) {
                                col = '<input type="button" id="Btn'+row.ID+'"  onclick="TestFunc(' + row.ID + ')" value="Add" class="GridButton"/>';
                                btnid = "Btn"+row.ID; //set to a global for getting out grid
                            }
                            return col;
                        }
                        }
                    ]]                
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err)
            }
        }       
    }

    document.getElemntById(btnid); //getting button, radio or text (value,checked etc)
```